# PHP copy() throwing error

Tags: php, import

I'm processing a large number of zips and can't track down an error.

The problem is that after the import script runs for a while it suddenly stops with an error at a random zip file. If I try to re-run the script for only that single file, it works (so I exclude that the zip is faulty). 
The process is like this: Open zip archive, read content, copy images from the zip, close archive.

I have two questions: 
1. Why doesn't PHP simply return false instead of throwing the following error:

```
PHP Error[2]:     copy(zip:///path/to/file/319759.zip#nwh1131_1.jpg): failed to open stream: operation failed
```

1. Any ideas what the cause can be? Maybe something with the filesystem? (Server is running on Debian 7 wheezy)

Thanks

Comment: Are you enclosing the URL in quotes?

Comment: Buffering issues somewhere? That when the program thinks it's done writing, the system is still busy doing the actual writing, so files remain open for longer than the program expects and you run out of file handles eventually?